# powershell set database IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to set a database name in powershell using Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO. When I execute my script it runs in error with the following error text:

```
format-default : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default],  IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

The server is set as follows

```
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" $server 
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false;
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_Login("login");
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_Password("password")
```

`$srv.Databases | Select name`, 
shows me the proper databases, but when setting the database,

```
$db = $srv.Databases[$database]
```

the error is thrown.

This scrip does work in other sqlservers. 
Any solutions for this issue?

Comment: a) What is `$database` set to? b) What is the output of `$srv.Databases.GetType()`?

Comment: PS U:\> $srv.Databases.GetType()


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                             
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                             
True     False    DatabaseCollection                       Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase

Comment: PS U:\> $database
CRD_DEV

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the database "CRD_DEV" does not exist on the server where the script throws the error. 
That or the user does not have access to that database.

The `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown because there is no item in `$srv.Databases` that matches "CRD_DEV"

Comment: When I list the databases in that particular server it shows CRD_DEV amongst master, model, msdb and tempdb. Strange thing is that I can login in MS SQL Server Managent Studio with the same credentials as used in my script.

Comment: Logging in is different from opening the database. Can you expand the database and do a select on a table in MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Could this be version related? When I want to check the properties of the database in  MS SQL Server Management Studio it shows Cannot read property UserAccess.This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: Can you output this variable `$srv.Databases`?

Comment: Where are you running the powershell? Is it in a SQL Server console?

Comment: $srv.Databases

format-default : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $srv.Databases | out-string
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

Comment: But then again: $srv.Databases |select Name

Name

CRD_DEV
master
model
tempdb

Comment: Perhaps you can try to execute your powershell from a standalone Powershell Console. You will have to load the smo assembly yourself  `Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'`

Comment: I tried that too, it also returns IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Maybe one last thing you can try is replace `$db = $srv.Databases[$database]` with `$db = $srv.Databases | where { $_.Name -eq $database }`

Comment: It runs into the same exception. I'm also a bit lost as to what a solution could be. The only think I can think of is that the version of sql server might be the issue.
I'm running against Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64). 
The server on which the script runs properly is running against Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64).
Maybe a service pack is required for SQL Server 2012.
Anyway, thanks for your help.